# SELECT OR JOIN ON MYSQL when function returns PK

Tags: mysql, function, join, subquery, primary-key

I have function which returns Id (PK)

When I make

```
select * from myTable WHERE PK = function(params)
```

db scans every row in myTable

MySql version 5/6/10

I saw some discussions here [How to use a SQL Function with INNER JOIN in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811363/how-to-use-a-sql-function-with-inner-join-in-mysql)
but how to solve problem without any tricks and screew methods ?

Answer (score 0):

Using functions in the `WHERE` clause makes MySql ignore any indexes that's why it does a full table scan.

See other's posts and explanation [here](http://blog.cnizz.com/2008/08/08/using-functions-in-mysql-where-clauses-breaks-speed-gains-from-indexing/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929808/why-mysql-does-not-use-indexes-in-where-if-clause/10930414#10930414)

Comment: I'm not sure how the function is implemented in mssql but the difference could be due to the database's support for `function-based index`. MySql doesn`t support it while mssql does via `computed column` http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/functions